# How to find the position of a specific character in a string with sparql

Tags: string, position, sparql, charindex

I'm trying to find a solution to find a character in a sting with sparql.

I tried the following code but there seems to be no option like CHARINDEX in SPARQL.

I want to find the position of the last "/" used in the URI (which i stranslated to a string with the STR function). So i can do something like "give me al characters of this string after the last backslash found in this string".

In Sql I would simply find the character with charindex() and define the lenght of the string with the LEN() function or so.

ORDER BY ?subject

PREFIX skos: http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?subject a skos:Concept .
  BIND(STRAFTER(STR(?subject), 'begrip/') as ?test)

}

Comment: Impossible with standard SPARQL. Some triple stores do support custom functions though, so you could have a look into the docs of your current triple store

Comment: or maybe you find some weird string hacks, that combine `replace`, `strlen` etc. -

Comment: what is the use-case? Getting the local name of a URI?

Comment: Yes, `strlen` and `replace` will do it, e.g something like `bind (strlen(replace(str(?iri), "(.+/)(.+)$", "$1")) as ?r)`